# Cannot add more projects to a Local Git under VS2019?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I'm fairly new to using Git.  I have read several question threads on VS and Git, but none seem to quite cover the scenario I'm looking at.

I have a solution that has 4 projects.  The primary project ("COHADWebApp") is registered under a Local Git repo (along with the solution), but I can't seem to add the other three projects to Git under the same solution.

These other 3 projects sources do sit outside of the folder path that the "COHADWebApp" project resides under - could this difference in folder paths be part of the issue?  (These additional projects are related, although each are distinct apps)

[My VS Solution showing only one project under Git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8eun.png)

E.g. with the "PortalMIReports" project selected, I **don't** get the File -> Add to Source Control option.  Right-clicking on the project shows no "Git" context-menu option either.

If I open the same project directly on it's own, I **do** then see options to add it to Source Control, which I guess I could live with (if slightly more awkward), but would prefer to be able to manage them under the one "umbrella" solution view if at all possible, to save having multiple VS instances open.

Am I doing something wrong?  Does Local Git support this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> These other 3 projects sources do sit outside of the folder path that the "COHADWebApp" project resides under - could this difference in folder paths be part of the issue?

Yes, that's in all likelihood the reason.

You initialize a git repository in a folder (the step was probably done by VisualStudio) and you are only able to track changes done on files inside this folder.

So if the other projects files are outside this directory, you can't add them to the git repository.

One of the solution here is to use the file explorer to move all the files and folders inside the folder of the git repository. Find the `.git` folder that could be hidden, that's the folder constituting your git repository.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks.  Rather than disrupt the original paths I'll just take the hit on individual VS sessions and keep the versioning separate.